# Compilation Error With Mesosphere RENDLER

Tags: c++, mesos, mesosphere

After attempting to compile Mesosphere's RENDLER in c++ with `make all`, I receive the following error:

```
$ make all
g++  -g -O2 -pthread -o rendler rendler.cpp -lmesos -lpthread -lprotobuf
In file included from /usr/local/include/stout/stringify.hpp:26:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/stout/bytes.hpp:26,
                 from /usr/local/include/mesos/resources.hpp:29,
                 from rendler.cpp:30:
/usr/local/include/stout/hashmap.hpp:43:32: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘<’ token
   hashmap(std::initializer_list<std::pair<Key, Value>> list)
                                ^
rendler.cpp:345:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
 }
 ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/stout/stringify.hpp:26:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/stout/bytes.hpp:26,
                 from /usr/local/include/mesos/resources.hpp:29,
                 from rendler.cpp:30:
/usr/local/include/stout/hashmap.hpp:40:14: error: expected unqualified-id at end of input
   hashmap() {}
              ^
make: *** [rendler] Error 1
```

I have all of the listed dependencies installed as well as the relevant 3rd party libraries in the correct include path. I receive the same error when attempting to compile the example frameworks in the `mesos/src/examples` directory. What is causing this error?

Comment: you forgot to include `-std=c++11`

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code

```
     std::initializer_list<std::pair<Key, Value>>
  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

causes the error

```
 error: expected ‘)’ before ‘<’ token
```

for pre stanadard c++11 compilers, since [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) was earliest introduced with c++11.

Most of the up-to date compilers like GCC allow to set the `-std=c++11` option, which should fix your error.